# Download several files from a url using R

Tags: r, loops, download

I would like to download all the zip files form this [website](https://www4.bcb.gov.br/fis/cosif/estban.asp?frame=1) using R. However, I would like to download "Relatório por município" and "Relatório por município e agência" separately. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www4.bcb.gov.br/fis/cosif/estban.asp?frame=1'
#Read webpage
webpage <- url %>% read_html()
#Extract links to download from "Relatório por município"
links1 <- webpage %>%
           html_nodes('div.centralizado select#ESTBAN_MUNICIPIO option') %>%
           html_attr('value') %>%
           paste0('https://www4.bcb.gov.br', .)
#Download the files
lapply(links1, function(x) download.file(x, paste0('ESTBAN_MUNICIPIO/', basename(x))))

#Extract links to download from "Relatório por município e agência"
links2 <- webpage %>%
            html_nodes('div.centralizado select#ESTBAN_AGENCIA option') %>%
            html_attr('value') %>%
            paste0('https://www4.bcb.gov.br', .)
#Download the files
lapply(links2, function(x) download.file(x, paste0('ESTBAN_AGENCIA/', basename(x))))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

" Error in download.file(x, paste0("ESTBAN_MUNICIPIO/", basename(x))) : 
  cannot open destfile 'ESTBAN_MUNICIPIO/202002_ESTBAN.ZIP', reason 'No such file or directory' "

Comment: I could fix it. I just had to put the name of a directory in 'ESTBAN_AGENCIA/'. Thank you!